# How to get height of div, after dimension of elements in div has been changed by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem with updating `div` height after elements in it has been changed.

Basically I have three files:

index.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>Template1</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="respond.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <img class= "img_center_big" src = "img.png">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

style.css:

```
body
{
    width:100%;
}

img
{
    max-height:1000px;
}

#wrapper
{
    background-color: yellow;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

respond.js:

```
 $("#wrapper").ready(function(){
  console.log($("#wrapper").height());
  $("#wrapper .img_center_big").width($("#wrapper").width() * 0.9 );
  $("#wrapper").height("auto");
  console.log($("#wrapper").height());
 });
```

The problem is that, `$("#wrapper").height()` is the same, even after changing it. Is there any solution for this? I've looked around, but couldn't find answer to this.

I want to get height of div after it's components has been changed with jQuery.

**EDIT:** Changed file name in post, made a typo.

Comment: You haven't changed the height though. A div's height is set to `auto` initially, then you updated it to `auto`. Therefore they are the same height. Example fiddle of changing height: http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/jnLzE/

Comment: Yes, but why isn't height changing after img size has been changed ? / Still not what I'm asking (thx for help tho ;)). You change height of wrapper, I'm changing element inside div, and I want to get height of div after his contents made him bigger.

Comment: It isn't the obvious is it? file called response.js, html referencing respond.js, or is this a typo here only?

Comment: I don't see the point of using jQuery, native Javascript or any other thing here but CSS to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

He is correct, you have not changed the height() value. You could iterate through all elements, in the DIV, and set the new height of the DIV to the sum total of all child elements height within it.

From what the code is you have shown, I would think this would be a stable route to take.

```
var totalsum = 0;

$("#wrapper").ready(function(){       
   $("#wrapper").children().each(function(){
      totalsum = totalsum + $(this).height();
   });


   console.log($("#wrapper").height());
   $("#wrapper .img_center_big").width($("#wrapper").width() * 0.9 );

   if(totalsum > 0)
   {
      $("#wrapper").height(totalsum);
    }

   console.log($("#wrapper").height());
  });
```

This is basic, but should offer the idea.  Hope it helps!

Comment: I like the idea but still it's not working :/ But console always writes 0. If i set img height to  10px in style.css it's writing 10. But if I change it in the script to something else it still display 10, as in css file.

Comment: I tested it in a fiddle, and is logging in console, and recalculating correct size.  Here is the fiddle.  What browser are you using? I am testing it in Chrome. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cpharr/LWTpW/

Comment: If you change    $("#wrapper .img_center_big").width($("#wrapper").width() * 0.9 ); to    $("#wrapper .img_center_big").width($("#wrapper").width() * 0.1 ); [0.9 to 0.1]. It still display with 40. But should display different   dimension  if the multiplier has been changed

Comment: I see what you are saying.....  Weird. It changes, but not when reporting it to console.

Comment: I am seeing both height, and width change correctly in UI, and in console log. Your code is changing the width() value, but checking if the height() value has changed. When you check for width(), it is correctly being modified.   Your console.log is looking at value "HEIGHT", and you are changing the value "WIDTH". Hence when after changing the modifier amount, you are seeing no difference. I updated the fiddle, if you want to check it out.

Comment: Thats the thing :) I want it to calculate height of element, and display it. Even if height is not set, i has to have height and thats what I'm looking for :)

Comment: "I like the idea but still it's not working :/ But console always writes 0. If i set img height to 10px in style.css it's writing 10. But if I change it in the script to something else it still display 10, as in css file."  If height is not set, or set, the value is still modified by the script changing it. I am just trying to see where the problem is.. If height is not set, it will still have a height property. Anyways, sorry I couldn't help. I have become lost on this one...  lol Sorry man.  Sorry could not give you a solution.

Comment: I'm still going to plus your comments - maybe I cant express myself enough :/

Comment: Well thanks. Though, I hate how everyone is "not assuming you" here to "Get Scores". I love this site to help, to learn, and anything else. Good luck!